# Set <tr> linear-gradient from right to left

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients

I want to set tr background-color based on percentage.
So I used `background-image: linear-gradient(green, green)` style for my tr.
The problem is `background-image` start from left and I want to fill color from right to left.
This is my style:

```
.table-row {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, green);
  background-size: 24%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

How can I solve it?
Working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h8vLd4sq/

Comment: `linear-gradient(green, green);` Are you sure?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW I want to tr has just e.g. green color, so I don't know how Implement it without `linear-gradient`

Comment: you mean entire tr should be green? and only the first row or all the rows in green?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I want to set color based on percentage. SO if percentage is 100% entire tr will be green and if it is 50%, half of it.

Comment: Ok got it, but what about right to left? does that mean the color should start from end of `tr`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yes, e.g. when percentage is 24% third column must be colored not first one.

Comment: @BeHappy I have updated my code, let me know if that is what you need? it is based on %, you can change % to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can add degree to set rotation
https://jsfiddle.net/4mLdozyp/1/

```
   .table-row {
     background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg,green 33%, white 0%);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: So u want whole row then remove background size there and  write right only. then whole row will be effected . I edited answer. Is that what u expected

Comment: I want unmixed color. just green.

Comment: it is unmixed .u tooked answered before last edited

Comment: This is start from left, too.

Comment: Do u want this green at the end of row ? deg shows its rotation, -90deg says goes from right then %75 percent make white then %25 percent make green

Comment: Yes, Start from end and has uniform green color. I used `background-image` because when I use `background-color` entire tr will be colored.

Comment: can u check  if it is ?

Comment: Yes, tnx, I also found this: `linear-gradient(to right, white 60%, green 10%);`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.table-row {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 60%, green 10%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want unmixed color, like `background-color`. but with `background-color` entire tr will be colored.

Comment: You just have to change the color, I have added white for visualization, you can change whichever color you need.

Comment: Run code plz, The green color slowly become white. I want that 40% has uniform green color.

Comment: @BeHappy don't you think this is the one I shared it earlier to earlier!? may be you didn't see it? this was the 2nd edit I did during that time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't see your answer.